# undefined is not an object ( evaluating 'react2.propTypes.oneOfTypes')

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

**Getting**

> undefined is not an object ( evaluating '_react2.PropTypes.oneOfType')

While using react-native-camera .

using react-native-camera@0.6 with following react native version.

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.55.2
```

What i tried inside app.js is

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
```

and

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

But not worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PropTypes` package has been separated from `react` since **v15.5** as mentioned [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

Since you're using an older version of `react-native-camera`, therefore they contain *old dependencies* in their `index.js`

**react-native-camera index.js v0.6** contains

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
```

Therefore you need to update the package since they have major changes and revamped folder structure as seen in [Camera.js](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/master/src/Camera.js)